# Posting to group using facebook nodejs sdk : OAuthException

Tags: node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to post to facebook group wall using nodejs sdk ( https://github.com/node-facebook/facebook-node-sdk )

This is a piece of code I am using :

Access token ( works fine ) :

```
FB.api('oauth/access_token', {
                client_id: appId,
                client_secret: appSecret,
                grant_type: 'client_credentials'
            }, function (res) {

                if (!res || res.error) {
                    var errorMessage = !res ? 'Unkown error' : res.error;
                    log.error(site + " Failed to get fb access token " + errorMessage);
                }

                var accessToken = res.access_token;
                FB.setAccessToken(accessToken);
            });
```

Attempt to post :

```
                var message = 'Hi from facebook-node-js';
                FB.api( facebookGroupId + '/feed', 'POST', {
                  //  access_token: appToken,
                    message: message
                }, function (res) {
                    if (!res || res.error) {
                        console.error(!res ? 'error occurred' : res.error);
                        return;
                    }
                    console.log('Post Id: ' + res.id);
                });
```

Which fails with :

```
{ message: '(#200) The user hasn\'t authorized the application to perform this action',
  type: 'OAuthException',
  code: 200,
  fbtrace_id: 'xxxxx' }
```

Now , this being a server side app, I can not pop something up to request the permission . Can someone point me where I  can assign the needed permission to the app ?

Comment: You need to pop something. That is the only way to get permissions from a user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to have access-token to get this done, It is obvious no user would like any app to save her facebook credentials. So right approach is to first pop-up that yields access token and make use of it for posting.

Comment: yes seems getting explicit permission from user is the way to go . so have to re-do part of the process now :(

Answer (score 1):

You need the user to grant user_managed_groups and publish_actions permission to do so. Keep in mind that both permissions need to be reviewed by Facebook.